# Merging users causes exception, failure

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, merge-accounts

I'm trying to merge two users on Programmers.SE:

- [dreza1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/27800/dreza1) (ID: 27800)
- [dreza1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/27674/dreza1) (ID: 27674)

such that ID: 27800 is merged into ID 27674.

However, when running the merge, an exception is thrown and the merge is not completed:

> Merge encountered an exception when merging User.Id = 27800 into master User.Id = 27674 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserHistory' with unique index 'UserHistory_UserId_CreationDay_Filtered_Unique'.

I can provide the full stack trace upon request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been fixed in the code.  After next build blah blah. (:

Comment: Your backwards smilies cause me to throw a parsing exception...can you fix that in the next build?

Comment: @sixlettervariables, [status-bydesign] q:

Comment: [status-brain-esplode]

Comment: Oh wow... there's another Rebecca who does (: smilies---I feel like we have so much in common.  [Obligatory XKCD comic](https://www.xkcd.com/165/).  I started typing (: when my ")" key broke when I was a teenager, and it became a habit ever since.